# Unauthorized when fetching Tasks with Microsoft graph

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I want to fetch my tasks within Javascript and possibly add new ones, but let's focus on fetching a task.

I made an app and use the msal.js file to get a token. I get prompted to allow the app to read/write from my account, the popup closes and I've obtained a token!

So far so good, but when I try to fetch my tasks the API responds with "unauthorized". When I check the headers I can see I sent along "bearer [token]" however.

I'm completely clueless on how to get my tasks by now since I did get a proper token and I've followed the guided setup to make sure I send along the token.

In my app (which I created on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) I've set all Task related permissions and User.read for good measure. As for the platform I've set "Web".

Is there something I'm missing or mis-configuring?
[image: My network tab in Chrome]

**My init method:**

```
const self = this
this.userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(this.clientID, null, function (errorDes, token, error, tokenType) {
  // this callback is called after loginRedirect OR acquireTokenRedirect (not used for loginPopup/aquireTokenPopup)
})

this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup(['Tasks.readwrite']).then(function (token) {
  let user = self.userAgentApplication.getUser()
  if (user) {
    self.token = token
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    self.getTasks()
  }
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```

**My getTasks method:**

```
  const bearer = 'Bearer ' + this.token
  let headers = new Headers()
  headers.append('Authorization', bearer)
  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
  }

  // Note that fetch API is not available in all browsers
  fetch('https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/tasks', options).then(function (response) {
    let contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
    if (response.status === 200 && contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
      response.json().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
    } else {
      response.json().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token is scoped for Graph, not Outlook. `Tasks.readwrite` will default to the Microsoft Graph and won't work against the Outlook endpoint.

Change this bit:

```
this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup(['Tasks.readwrite'])
```

To:

```
this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup(['https://outlook.office.com/Tasks.readwrite'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It doesn't seem to make any change, sadly :(
One of the response headers is `x-ms-diagnostics:2000001;reason="Token type is not known.";error_category="invalid_token"`

Comment: You might parse your token with something like https://jwt.io and see if it's valid.

Comment: Got it working now, made a typo apparently. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Microsoft Graph, so the request should look like 
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/outlook/tasks`

It's documented here:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/outlookuser_list_tasks

I believe you got a Microsoft Graph token but you're trying to use it on the Outlook REST endpoint, which would not work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I'm near my macbook, thanks! On another note: Which/what would work (best) to get my Microsoft ToDo tasks/lists?